# Camera shows ghost lighting or refrective image

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

Once I have updated to iOS 12 beta 10 , my camera shows strange reflective images. Suppose if I am taking photo of my television in low light, it shows blurry image of my tv just below an original photo, doesn’t seems like glare but much more than this, also Pictures of CFL and tube light shows refractive image. Is it software issue? Also it seems happening after 1 month of purchase. Lens is clean , no physical damage too. Is there anyway to fix it?[image: CFL Shows refrective image][image]

Comment: Could you post a picture with an example?

Comment: I have posted it, can you see refrective image of CFL , that’s how it’s creating image

Comment: It looks like simple optical reflection inside the lens structure. All cameras will do that if you point at a bright light-source. This particular type where the reflection is precisely opposite the centre of the lens is known as ghosting - here is a good explanation - https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/35054/57929

Answer (score 1):

This lens flare is due to the geometry of the camera and the physical aperture / focus ring and might be normal or might be signs that the internals have shifted or become damaged. A hard drop can knock the camera out of alignment and cause this. Also, there are lighting conditions that guarantee a properly assembled and working iPhone camera makes that flare.

- Take controlled photos with other devices if you wish to rule out that it's just the natural result of that light bouncing off the camera. Get a lens hood or change the exposure is how photographers manage this (this problem is just one of optics and sensors) if it turns out your device is working like others.
- Take the phone (camera) in for service if you believe it's not working as designed and you can't see any signs of physical damage or a drop. If the phone isn't up to spec - Apple or their service team will offer a repair under warranty assuming you're covered. The only thing I would expect to pay is if I damaged it (warranty doesn't cover drops or breaks).

Comment: Or - take that lens flare and go make movies and art! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALHiJaSPrns

Answer (score 0):

do you mean this ?
it looks like reflection.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it’s creating images like this while indoor and in low light I can see multiple dots.

Comment: Image you have indicated, is image of CFL which is lighten above

Comment: I have added one more picture in which longer tube lights creating its own image. I have googled it and found multiple apple users are impacted with issue worldwide, is it a manufacturing defect, hardware issue or software issue , I am not sure, but seems like an issue which persists from 2016 but apple never addressed it.

Comment: FYI - I haven’t took tv pictures which I have mentioned earlier in my post but even Indoor lights examples are enough to understand the problem I am trying to indicate. It seems like glare but much more than thst